# Python Unit Test Replace Class with Fake

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm attempting to replace a class with a fake class in my Python unit test:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from foobar import compute_bfux

def test_compute_bfux_succeed(self):
    paramA, paramB, expected_result = 8, 11, 63

    with patch('utility.functions') as fake:
        fake = FakeUtilityFunctions()
        actual_result = compute_bfux(paramA, paramB)
    
    self.assertEqual(actual_result, expected_result)
```

In the above, `FakeUtilityFunctions` is an actual class I've written. I want to swap in "FakeUtilityFunctions" class for "utility.functions" in `compute_bfux`.

Unfortunately, the above doesn't work. In `compute_bfux`, I get a MagicMock, which isn't what I want. I know `utility.functions` is being swapped out with a MagicMock because I end up with the following error when running my test...

> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and
> 'MagicMock'

Can someone who sees where I'm trying to go tell me where I'm screwing this up?

Comment: I don't understand the utility of this, there is no point where the fake is being used in the function. Could you elaborate on why the "fake" is necessary. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what specially you are trying to patch and what you are trying to test. Where does `compute_bfux` come from? Does it call the utility function you are patching or are you trying to patch *it* for some reason?

Comment: @MarkMeyer `test_compute_bfux_succeed` is testing a function named `compute_bfux`. `compute_bfux` calls a handful of functions in `utility.functions`. For the test, I want to replace `utility.functions` with a fake. The fake will have a custom implementation of functions employed by `compute_bfux`.

Comment: @Adam `fake = FakeUtilityFunctions()` isn't going to work, as you've discovered. All that is doing is replacing the reference in the local name `fake`. You more likely want to pass `FakeUtilityFunctions` as an argument to `patch` as [described here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
with patch('utility.functions') as fake:
    fake = FakeUtilityFunctions()
```

Instead, do this:

```
with patch('utility.functions', wraps=FakeUtilityFunctions()):
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: Had to remove `()`.  This worked `with patch('utility.functions', wraps=FakeUtilityFunctions):`